# Pop-Up works only once (Animista)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building my first HTML/CSS/js website and started working with pop-ups today, using Animista. I am making a simple scale-in / scale-out pop-up module which scales-in when you click a button, and scales-out when you click a close button.

For some reason this works only once: I close the pop-up, it does not show up when I press a button again. It works only if I reload the page. (I work locally now) I have been looking for an answer myself, but can't find anything helpful (i guess I google wrong keywords...).

Sorry if the question is obvious -- I am very new to web development. Thank you so much!!

See the code below:

css:

```
.scale-in-tr {
    -webkit-animation: scale-in-tr 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
    animation: scale-in-tr 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-3-6 10:48:23
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */
/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation scale-up-tr
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-3-6 11:13:44
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */
/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation scale-in-tr
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
@-webkit-keyframes scale-in-tr {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes scale-in-tr {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.scale-out-tr {
    -webkit-animation: scale-out-tr 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
    animation: scale-out-tr 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.550, 0.085, 0.680, 0.530) both;
}

/* ----------------------------------------------
 * Generated by Animista on 2020-3-6 11:47:17
 * Licensed under FreeBSD License.
 * See http://animista.net/license for more info. 
 * w: http://animista.net, t: @cssanimista
 * ---------------------------------------------- */
/**
 * ----------------------------------------
 * animation scale-out-tr
 * ----------------------------------------
 */
@-webkit-keyframes scale-out-tr {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes scale-out-tr {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
        -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: black;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.box-two {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: black;
}

.box {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center ;
    max-height: 400px;
    min-height: 150px;
}

.three {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center ;
    margin: auto;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
}

.na {
    height: 150px;
}

footer {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.invis {
    background-color: blue;
    align-self: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.four {
    align-self: auto;
}

.five {
    width: 65px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pop-up {
    background-color: black;
    border: 1.5px solid white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 350px;
    max-width: 80%;
    transform: scale(0);
    position: absolute;
    right: 70px;
    top: 70px;
    /* opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;*/
}

.pop-up-active {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.pop-up.about-containter {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    color: white;
}

.about-text {
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 15px 15px;
}

.pop-up-footer {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.close-pop {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background: none;
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: white;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

js:

```
var boxTwo = document.querySelector('.box-two');

boxTwo.addEventListener("click", e => {
  document.querySelector(".pop-up").classList.toggle("scale-in-tr")
});

var closePop=document.querySelector('.close-pop');

closePop.addEventListener("click", e=>{
    document.querySelector(".pop-up").classList.toggle("scale-out-tr")
});
```

Comment: I think it is maybe because of classList.toggle, you are adding class  "scale-out-tr"  close which will stay on element when you close it, but when you try to open again it will have that class "scale-out-tr" and there is some conflict i guess, try with classList.add and classList.remove. If you reload it works again because it resets everything.

Comment: @Alco this worked, however, as I understand, that means that I can use only one animation -- I add and remove 'scale-in-tr' .

Comment: @Alco Originally, I wanted on-click pop-up to scale from 0 to 100% and back from 100% to 0% when pressing 'close' button. With classList.add and classList.remove I use only one animation (not sure, maybe I can reverse it in js?)

Comment: You can use this one also "scale-out-tr" for close animation but you have  to remove scale-in-tr after clicking, that means:

                        `closePop.addEventListener("click", e=>{
        document.querySelector(".pop-up").classList.add("scale-out-tr")
        document.querySelector(".pop-up").classList.remove("scale-in-tr")
    }); `

Also for boxTwo you will need remove class for "scale-out-tr" if there is some conflict you can add setTimeout like 100ms to execute remove clas

Comment: Can you put up a code snippet on CodePen or jsfiddle illustrating the issue ?